# Does Google Music match?

Tags: google-play-music

Does Google Music match my music with it's own database? 
A lot of Sources are claiming that, however it seems to just upload my Music (ie: The tags aren't updated)

What is right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Music recently launched in Europe](http://www.theverge.com/2012/11/16/3653210/google-play-music-scan-and-match-europe) and one of the claimed features is "scan and match".

According to The Verge, this is Europe-only for now and, at least during their checks, only seems to be working in the UK.

So, depending where you are, the answer to your question is: not yet, but soon.

Update: [This has gone live in the United States](https://plus.google.com/+GooglePlay/posts/VZhB6EpsWKx).

Comment: I live in Germany so this is probably the problem. Edit: To Clarify: Matching just works in the UK? Google Music is working fine here in Germany (it just don't seem to match)

Comment: That's what The Verge says. I live in the U.S. so I can't confirm anything. I expect it'll get rectified within a few weeks.